# Extract first two lines of PDF with Python and pyPDF

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypdf

I'm using python 2.7 and pyPDF to get the title meta info from PDF files. Unfortunately not all of PDF have the meta info. What I want to do now is grab the first two line of text from a PDF. Using what I have now how can I modify the code to capture the first two lines with pyPDF?

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os

for fileName in os.listdir('.'):
    try:
        if fileName.lower()[-3:] != "pdf": continue
        input1 = PdfFileReader(file(fileName, "rb"))

        # print the title of document1.pdf
        print fileName, input1.getDocumentInfo().title
    except:
        print ",",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os
import StringIO

fileName = "HMM.pdf"
try:
        if fileName.lower()[-3:] == "pdf": 
            input1 = PdfFileReader(file(fileName, "rb"))

            # print the title of document1.pdf
            #print fileName, input1.getDocumentInfo().title

            content = input1.getPage(0).extractText()
            buf = StringIO.StringIO(content)
            buf.readline()
            buf.readline()

except:
        print ",",
```

My pwd contains this "HMM.pdf" file and this code is working on python 2.7  properly.

Comment: can you show me a full example based off of my current code... it's not output anything when I add in the code you gave above.

Comment: hmm am I missing something still no output. have 5 pdf files in a folder i run the script and nothing

Comment: Try running each command on the interpreter and observe the output. I checked the above code, its working as long as there is valid file in the input1.

Comment: are you sure its working? make sure the line #print fileName, input1.getDocumentInfo().title us commented cause that line gets the title from the PDF meta info. Might be displaying false data.

Comment: Updated the exact code that i ran. It is working properly. Debug your program to check whats missing.